# How to setting up Sublime Text for python Competitive Programming Environment

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have read the article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setting-up-sublime-text-for-cpp-competitive-programming-environment/
and i want to do the same thing with python, but the result is not as expected, is there any way to do the same thing?

```
{
 "cmd":["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32\\python.exe", "-u", "$file",
 "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe",
 "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.out"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Comment: The article for for C++ using the MinGW Compiler. Try following this: https://towardsdatascience.com/run-python3-on-sublime-text-5949e55450b2

Comment: Well, for one thing, running a script with Python doesn't create an executable.

Answer (score 0):

### This method is not appropriate to python.

Writing a build system for python is not required as it is already implemented for you in Sublime Text.

### Here's how to use Sublime Text to run python code : \

Go to `Tools` then `Build System` then select `Python` 
To run your code, press Ctrl + B

### Note :

This method requires you to have already installed python. You can download it from https://www.python.org/downloads/.

### Small tip :

For more comfort, change the text type at the bottom left from `Plain Text` to `Python`, that will color your code to make it more comprehensible.